# javascript calling function as array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, call

I came across this example in a Toptal youtube video that uses syntax that won't run in Chrome, unless I am missing something.  This example comes up here ([JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)) and the same syntax is used.  Why is this not running for me/does the indicated line below contain valid syntax?

```
var x, y, funcs = [];

for(x=0; x<5; x++){

    (function(){
        var r = x;
        funcs.push(function(){
        console.log(r);
        });

    });
};  
for (var y=0; y<5; y++){
    funcs[y]();  //<< is this valid JS syntax/why is it not working for me?
};
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: You declare y as [] and then again as index, this might not be working as expected. Also retrieve a return value when iterating your array and try to check the result in a debugger.

Comment: The problem is not with the function call syntax; that's fine. The problem is that your first `for` loop isn't putting anything in the array. You've got an anonymous function that's *never called*, so the first loop does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make this anonymous function inside your first for-loop **self-executing** by adding a pair of brackets `()` after the definition.

```
(function(){
    var r = x;
    funcs.push(function(){
    console.log(r);
    });

})();
```

Without this, you keep declaring a function inside your first loop which is **never executed** and thus, never pushes anything into your array.

After your first loop, do a `console.log(funcs.length)` and you will get a `0` since your array has no elements.

Your current code will give you `uncaught type error: funcs[0] is not a function` which is because `funcs[0]` is `undefined`.

Comment: Probably should pass `x` to the function as well to avoid the closure/loop problem.

Comment: That shouldn't be required since all anonymous functions in the array have declared their own `var r`.

Comment: They do, that's true; I guess that should work fine!